# Hg diff with multiple files

Tags: mercurial

I am new to mercurial. So, please excuse my question if it sounds trivial. I am trying to figure out how to do a diff for multiple files. Here is my use case : I made changes to four files. However, I am only interested in seeing the changes I made in two of them (fileA and fileB). I thought something like this would work :

```
hg diff fileA fileB
```

But it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need either the `--include`(`-I`) or `--exclude`(`-X`) options such as:

```
hg diff -I fileA -I fileB
hg diff -X *.csv
```

Remember you can compare specific revisions too

```
hg diff -r 1234:tip -I fileA
```

Use `hg help diff` in the console to see all the options available or look [here](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#diff)